# Group and filter from list of objects c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of type class. I want to group by and filter based on one of the members of class. My code looks like below:

```
public class SP 
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } 
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
} 

List<sp> splist = new List<sp>();

 ID    Name            StartDate     EndDate
6025  'Bob'          '2010-05-10'    '2015-08-20'
6026  'Jessica'      '2012-01-15'    '2013-04-13'
6028  'Christina'    '2010-05-10'    '2016-11-20'
6029  'Chris'        '2011-03-20'    '2014-08-19'
6030  'James'        '2011-03-20'    '2012-08-28'
6031  'Morris'       '2009-06-12'    '2017-01-20'
```

I want to GroupBy and prepare a report based on the 'StartDate' property.
The actual value of StartDate will be known during runtime only.

Please help me with list group by with runtime value. I would like to have resultset as,

On first iteration,

6025  'Bob'          '2010-05-10'    '2015-08-20'
   6028  'Christina'    '2010-05-10'    '2016-11-20'

Second 
 6026  'Jessica'      '2012-01-15'    '2013-04-13' 

Third 
 6029  'Chris'        '2011-03-20'    '2014-08-19' 
       6030  'James'        '2011-03-20'    '2012-08-28' 

and on fourth 
    6031  'Morris'       '2009-06-12'    '2017-01-20'

Comment: I don't see how getting values from a db are relevant. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, "you are trying to group based on object `D`". But you don't want to hard code what you are trying to group by? Without knowing what you want to group by, why are you even needing to group the objects instead of just running through a foreach?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: If you group by `D`, what do you want to do with the other values (`B` and `D`) in the group? `Sum` them? Take the `Max`? Probably you should ask this in a slightly more specific way, with a realistic example and actual datatypes for your class properties. Including some sample data and expected output will go a long way to getting the answer you need.

Comment: Thanks Hari. Please update the question instead of the comments! It's much more readable and more likely that everyone will see it.

Comment: Thanks @RufusL Now, I have updated the question with more specifics.

Comment: I see you updated the class, thanks! Do you have some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I updated my answer with your new class. Is there something more you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Rufus. Let me go through.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified a filter for your class, but in your expected output it looks like you just want to use grouping and not filtering (since all the results are in the output, nothing was filtered).

One change I made in your `SP` class was to override the `ToString()` method so the class has a friendly way to display itself in the output:

```
public class SP
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var formattedName = (Name + " ").PadRight(13, '.');
        return $"{ID}: {formattedName} Started on: {StartDate:d}, Ended on: {EndDate:d}";
    }
}
```

Then I added a list of the sample data you provided:

```
// Sample data
var newlist = new List<SP>
{
    new SP {ID = 6025, Name = "Bob", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-05-10"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-08-20")},
    new SP {ID = 6026, Name = "Jessica", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-01-15"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-04-13")},
    new SP {ID = 6028, Name = "Christina", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-05-10"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-20")},
    new SP {ID = 6029, Name = "Chris", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-03-20"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-08-19")},
    new SP {ID = 6030, Name = "James", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-03-20"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-08-28")},
    new SP {ID = 6031, Name = "Morris", StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-06-12"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-20")},
};
```

Now, you can group this list by `StartDate` with a single line:

```
// Group on Property 'StartDate'
var groupedList = newlist.GroupBy(a => a.StartDate).ToList();
```

And finally, to look at the members of each group, we can cast each group to a `List`, which will be a list of the `SP` objects in the group. We can also reference the `group.Key`, which is the property that we grouped by (`StartDate`). So displaying the groups might look something like:

```
foreach (var group in groupedList)
{
    var groupMembers = group.ToList();

    Console.WriteLine($"Members who have a Start Date of: {group.Key:d}");
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine($" - {string.Join("\n - ", groupMembers)}");
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Now, if you want to sort the group by the `StartDate` (which is the `group.Key`), then you can add an `OrderBy` clause:

```
// GroupBy and OrderBy Property 'StartDate'
var groupedList = newlist.GroupBy(a => a.StartDate).OrderBy(a => a.Key).ToList();
```

And now your output will be sorted, with the oldest start dates appearing first (you could change `OrderBy` to `OrderByDescending` if you want the most recent `StartDate` to come first):

[image]

Comment: I am looking to filter from runtime without hardcoding. In example, your filter condition is (Current date - 3) which is hardcoded one.

Comment: Well since you haven't specified what the filter is, I just made one up. What is the filter condition?

Comment: I see you've also added sample data and output, thank you! I have updated my example to use your data and shown how to get the group members and display them. I removed the filtering since it seems you don't really need that. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To use group by and convert to a list is easy:

```
var newlist = (from ar in db.A group ar by ar.D select ar).ToList();
```